# Why does "if statement" has to "die()", otherwise wont work?

Tags: api, json, rest-api

```
if ($_GET['api'] == 'json' && isset($_GET['id'])) {

        $post = get_post($_GET['id']);   // $post contains the post object   

        header("content-type: application/json");
        echo json_encode($post);
}
die();
```

This code works, but if I want to extend it will not work
In the second case(below) , if i write
  `?second=case&id=204` to the url i get `Unexpected`
but if I write `?first=case&id=204`  I get the request

```
if (isset($_GET['api'])) {
    if ($_GET['first'] == 'case' && isset($_GET['id'])) {
         // $query is the WP_Query Object
        $post = get_post($_GET['id']);   // $post contains the post object   

        header("content-type: application/json");
        echo json_encode($post);
    }
    if ($_GET['second'] == 'case' && isset($_GET['id'])) {
         // $query is the WP_Query Object
        $post = get_post($_GET['id']);   // $post contains the post object   

        header("content-type: application/json");
        echo json_encode($post);
    }
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's simply because `$_GET['first']` is not defined when you try with `?second=case&id=204`.

Instead, try this CODE (assuming `first` & `second` can't appear at the same time):

```
if (isset($_GET['api'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['first']) && $_GET['first'] == 'case' && isset($_GET['id'])) {
         // $query is the WP_Query Object
        $post = get_post($_GET['id']);   // $post contains the post object   

        header("content-type: application/json");
        echo json_encode($post);
    }
    else if (isset($_GET['second']) && $_GET['second'] == 'case' && isset($_GET['id'])) {
        // $query is the WP_Query Object
        $post = get_post($_GET['id']);   // $post contains the post object   

        header("content-type: application/json");
        echo json_encode($post);
    }
    die();
}
```

Comment: But why the die has to be there?

Comment: If your CODE ends there, then `die()` doesn't need to be there. If your CODE still continues with any output at all, then `die()` is needed, since any output after `echo json_encode($post)` may break json.